Can't convert .o file created by NASM to .exe using GCC on Windows
I am trying to learn how to make apps using x86. I am using NASM to convert a .asm file to a .o file, then GCC to convert that .o file to a .exe file.
Here are the commands I used in Windows CMD:
nasm -f elf test.asm
gcc test.o

But upon running the second command, this error happens:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can someone identify the problem and a potential solution?

You are compiling assembly in the ELF format but you seem to have references to a Windows runtime. I'm guessing nasm is working as intended because you give it the -f elf flag but I'd bargain gcc is attempting to link the shared object against a Windows library.

With Windows (MinGW or Cygwin) GCC, you want nasm -f win32 or nasm -f win64 to make the right kind of object file.  If the asm is from a tutorial that recommended that nasm command, the asm source is probably for Linux, too, so it won't work on Windows (different symbol name convention: leading underscores.  For 32-bit the calling conventions are similar enough, at least cdecl, but some Windows functions use stdcall.)

If you want your assembly code to run then you will need to define a function _main: to start as an entry point and make it global with global _main
